# Standard behavior for direct initialization of unsigned short

Tags: c++, syntax, casting, initialization, language-lawyer

I noticed today that in the example code:

```
void print(unsigned short a) {
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Initialization and use works like this:

```
print(short (5));
```

But not like this:

```
print(unsigned short(6));
```

> main.cpp:16:8: error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'
>     print(unsigned short(6));

And it's not to do with the type since this also works:

```
typedef unsigned short ushort;
print(ushort (6));
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3af208b545af3a9a)

So I went searching for what the standard says about value initialization. It turns out nothing:

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 1) if T is a class type ...
>
> 2) if T is a non-union class type ...
>
> 2) if T is a class type ...
>
> 3) if T is an array type, ..
>
> 4) **otherwise**, the object is zero-initialized.

*Modifications made for readability.* [Original source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

What are the rules about value initialization of [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) types? What is the reason that `unsigned` qualified types can't be value initialized? Is this more to do with the fact they are `rvalues`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What is the reason that `unsigned` qualified types can't be value initialized?

It's just because only single-word type name could be used in [functional cast expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), while `unsigned short` is not a single-word type name; `short` is.

> The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid), followed by a single expression in parentheses.

As you showed, you can use `typedef` as the workaround, or add parentheses to change it to c-style cast expression, e.g. `(unsigned short)(6)`, or `(unsigned short)6`.

From the standard, [§7.6.1.3/1 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#1):

> A [simple-type-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple) or [typename-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res) followed by a parenthesized optional expression-list or by a braced-init-list (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer.

And [simple-type-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple):

> ```
> simple-type-specifier:
>   nested-name-specifier opt
>  type-name
>   nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id
>   nested-name-specifier opt
>  template-name
>   char
>   char16_t
>   char32_t
>   wchar_t
>   bool
>   short
>   int
>   long
>   signed
>   unsigned
>   float
>   double
>   void
>   auto
>   decltype-specifier
> type-name:
>   class-name
>   enum-name
>   typedef-name
>   simple-template-id
> decltype-specifier:
>   decltype ( expression )
>   decltype ( auto )
> ```

[typename-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier):

> ```
> typename-specifier:
>   typename nested-name-specifier identifier
>   typename nested-name-specifier template opt
>  simple-template-id
> ```

Comment: Ahh, ok, its not even value initialization. Makes sense. Good answer.

Comment: A Follow up question which is heavily related is why in value initialization does not cover `other types`. In this expression `unsigned int i(6)` is it value initialized, or zero initialized?

Comment: Note that `(unsigned short)()`, i.e., trying to use *value initialisation* does not work. `(unsigned short){}` does work, though.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox `unsigned int i(6)` is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). `i` is initialized to `6`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I obviously have some work to do learning initialization names.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'm not sure why, is it just invalid syntax?

Comment: @songyuanyao: seems like it. At least, gcc, clang, and icc all agree that the syntax isn't valid. I didn't know that parenthesis for the type work with direct initialisation at all, i.e., that you can get away without a type alias.

Answer (score 7):

That's just a glitch in the grammar: the two word type names don't work when creating temporary objects. That is, none of these work

```
template <typename T> void use(T);
int main() {
    use(unsigned int());
    use(const int());
    use(long long());
}
```

The work-around is to use an alias for the respective type instead, i.e., all of these do work:

```
template <typename T> void use(T);
int main() {
     { using type = unsigned int; use(type()); }
     { using type = const int; use(type()); }
     { using type = long long; use(type()); }
 }
```

Parenthesis can also be used for value initialisation although the require the use of curlies:

```
template <typename T> void use(T);
int main() {
     use((unsigned int){});
     use((const int){});
     use((long long){});
}
```