# braced-init-list and unsigned types

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, language-lawyer

gcc 8 and clang 7 do not accept the following code, which should default-construct a temporary of type `unsigned int`:

```
unsigned int ui = unsigned int{};
```

clang 7 reports an error such as

```
<source>:6:22: error: expected primary-expression before 'unsigned'
```

Visual C++ 2015 and 2017 accept this.

Obviously, this works with a type such as `int`, or any default-constructible class type.

Is this correct C++14 code (and in that case a bug of clang and gcc)? If not, why not? Which types other than unsigned types would suffer from the same restriction?

Comment: Try `(unsigned int){};`. Think of the {} applied only to `int` and then there's `unsigned` hanging where it shouldn't, hence the error message.

Comment: @DeiDei that is a syntax error in Standard C++  (parenthesized typename followed by `{` does not match any grammar rule)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`new_type { expression-list(optional) }` like `unsigned int{}` fits the syntax of [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), which allows only single-word type name.

> A single-word type name followed by a braced-init-list is a prvalue of the specified type `designating a temporary (until C++17)` `whose result object is (since C++17)` direct-list-initialized with the specified braced-init-list.

Note that `unsigned int` is not a single-word type name, while `int` is. So `int {}` works fine.

This is same for *functional cast expression*,

> The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid),

As a workaround, you can apply type alias, e.g.

```
using type = unsigned int;
type ui = type{};
```

Comment: Thanks. Obviously, it is not a single word, I wasn't aware of this constraint.

Comment: @user2019765 I agree this is not easy to notice; even it's obvious if you realize it.

Comment: Interestingly, adding parentheses works with clang, but not with Visual C++, there it yields an error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax

Comment: @user2019765 I'm not sure, but I think both accepting `unsigned int{}` and rejecting `(unsigned int){}` deosn't conform to the standard.

Comment: `(unsigned int){}` is not a C-style cast: a C-style cast has form `(type)expression`, and `{}` is not an expression. With `-pedantic`, g++ warns `ISO C++ forbids compound-literals` and clang warns `compound literals are a C99-specific feature`.

Comment: @songyuanyao a compiler could offer the first one as an extension but not offer the second  (both are syntax errors in Standard C++)

Comment: @M.M Which *the first one* and *the second one*?

Comment: @songyuanyao the first one is `unsigned int{}` and the second one is `(unsigned int){}`

Comment: @M.M I think `(unsigned int){}` is a *C-style cast* as `( new_type ) expression`, the problem it that whether `{}` is a valid expression. And why the compiler can't provide it as an extension? Is it prohibited explicitly?

Comment: @songyuanyao `{}` does not match the syntax for *expression*  . In contexts where an expression or a braced-list is allowed, the grammar rule will list expression and braced-list as separate options.  The compiler can provide extensions. I'm saying it's OK for the compiler to provide only one of these two things as an extension (you said the compiler was not allowed to do that)

Comment: @M.M I got it about `{}`. But still confusing why can't provide both as extension?

Comment: @songyuanyao it can provide both as extensions. I was responding to your claim that it cannot provide one whilst not providing the other (i.e. that it must provide both or neither)

Answer (score 3):

"Int" is optional in "unsigned int".

Try simply:

```
unsigned ui = unsigned{};
```

It works.

Edit:
I found this answer:
[Standard behavior for direct initialization of unsigned short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893895/standard-behavior-for-direct-initialization-of-unsigned-short/51893988#51893988)

> It's just because only single-word type name could be used in
>   functional cast expression, while unsigned short is not a single-word
>   type name; short is.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my question was not how to fix the expression, but if it is correct.