# How does a pointer (built-in types) which gets constructed like a custom class work?

Tags: c++

I've changed the question title and body see if it suits better :).

---

I read a member function signature on [cppreference: unique_ptr/reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset).

```
void reset( pointer ptr = pointer() ) noexcept;
```

and `pointer` is a member type of `unique_ptr`, [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as

> `pointer` | `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type exists, otherwise `T*`. Must satisfy `NullablePointer`

What I've learnt in the comments:

1. `pointer ptr = pointer()` is somehow equivalent to e.g. `int`, `using pointer = int*; pointer ptr = pointer()`
2. And if it's a built-in type like `int`, then `ptr` is a **zero-initialized** variable. I get a `int*` pointer with `0/NULL/nullptr` here.
3. There is not a "raw" statement for `using pointer = int*; pointer ptr = pointer()`, which is that `int* ptr = int*()` won't work.

I also read [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors)
 and that helps a lot.

---

I want to know a bit more about this behaviour(a built-in type can be constructed in a custom class way), if it can be explained in more details:

`using pointer = int*; pointer ptr = pointer()`

Seriously no "raw" syntax for this statment? I used to think that everything use a `typedef` or `using` could be written down with a "raw" version. Like a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Expect null pointer.

Comment: @Evg  Why? How? ... QAQ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default constructor for C++ pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936999/what-is-the-default-constructor-for-c-pointer)

Comment: @Evg Sorry I don't understand that linked question. I don't see arguments similar like `pointer ptr = pointer()` :(

Comment: `pointer` is `data_type` [and](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937119/1625187) "The expression `data_type()` evaluates to a default-initialized object. In case of non-POD types, the default constructor is invoked, but in case of POD types, such as pointers, default initialization is equivalent to zero initialization."

Comment: @Evg Ah I see. Let me check again. I just noticed that `pointer` is a type member of `unique_ptr`. Sorry I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Evg: That statement (partly due to its age, presumably) is confusing default-initialization with value-initialization, which is what `T()` does.

Comment: @DavisHerring, agree.

Comment: @Evg But how does that work ? For example, I can't initialize a pointer with `int* p = int*()`

Comment: The definition of `pointer` is `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer if that type exists, otherwise T*. Must satisfy NullablePointer`. `T* ptr = T*()` ?

Comment: Unless you use some fancy custom deleter, it is just `T*`. Try this for `int`: `using T = int*; T p = T();` or `int* p = (int*){};`.

Comment: @Evg But what's the equivalent of that without using `using`? using `using` only makes more confusion to me.. There must be a "raw"  format.

Comment: @Rick No, there need not be, and there isn't one. As a much more gratuitious example, `a.~int()` is an error, but `a.~T()` is a no-op for `int a; using T = int;`.

Comment: @Deduplicator ...seriously? I can't write that expression with raw type? OMG

Comment: There are some syntactic limitations. You should either use a `typedef`/`using` or curly braces.

Comment: I'm not sure about the correct quote from the standard. But if the type name is not a single word, you can't say `some type()` like `unsigned int()` or `int*()`. But if it is a single word like `pointer`, you can say `pointer()`, and if `pointer` is just a plain pointer like `int*`, `pointer()` means zero-initialization as explained in the linked question.

Comment: See this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization - "4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized."

Comment: @Evg: `(int*){}` is a compound literal; those exist in C but not C++.

Comment: @DavisHerring, thanks. It seems to be supported by Gcc and Clang as an extension.

Comment: @Evg Thanks. Things get much clearer after I read this post [Do built-in types have default constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113365/do-built-in-types-have-default-constructors). Also I think `int* p = (int*){};` may be the "raw" pattern(I just ran it on my machine and it compiles), as someone in that answer says *"So technically there are no constructors for basic-POD types. But for all intents and purposes they act just like they have a copy constructor and default constructor (**when initialized with the braces**)."*

Comment: As Davis noted above, `(int*){}` is not really standard C++, it is C. `using T = int*; T();` is the example with a raw pointer. You can't write it without `T`, because `int*` is not single-word type name. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336344/braced-init-list-and-unsigned-types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the "raw" syntax as you put it, since pointers can be zero initialized with a `0`.

```
int *p = 0; // nullptr
```

I guess it might be useful for template argument deduction, but we already have a syntax for that: `(int*)0`. There isn't really a need to add yet more syntax for something small like that (or maybe someone forgot to add it; but either way, it's unnecessary now).

The `T(...)` syntax is mostly used to initialize objects of user-defined types.

> I used to think that everything use a `typedef` or `using` could be written down with a "raw" version.

Here's another example:

```
int a;
a.~int(); // syntax error

using Int = int;
a.~Int(); // ok!
```

The first statement is disallowed because it's a no-op. The second isn't because in a generic context it might do something (destroy the object) instead of being a no-op. Since the language doesn't want to unnecessarily restrict this going through an alias is allowed.

It's for this same reason that `pointer()` is allowed even if you can't write out the syntax: If it would be disallowed it would be a pain to work in a generic context.

Comment: Makes a good point. A friend in chatroom also mentioned that "generic" part. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48085012#48085012

Comment: What's do you mean by saying "we alreay have `(int*)0`" ? Sorry I don't remember much about the template part. I just tested on my machine. I can only use `(int*)0` to initialize built-in types like `int, int*` , but not for custom class type. `(T)0` doesn't seem to be a substitude of `using pointer = int*; pointer ptr = pointer()`.

Comment: Another question: "The first statement is disallowed because it's a no-op. ". So `no-p == not allowed`? I know little about the `no-op` concept and how it interacts with the language.

Comment: @Rick `(T)0` yeah just built-in types. It's a no-op, so allowing it would be misleading since it doesn't do anything