# Possible gcc conformance issue upon initialization of auto variable?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

I test my code on both VS2022 and gcc 11.2.0 where I found that the simple code line does not compile only on gcc,

```
const auto FAV_TEST_VAL = unsigned char{ '9' };
```

With the following error,

```
g++ -c -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts rev.cpp
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp rev.o
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:11:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’
   11 |     const auto FAV_TEST_VAL = unsigned char{ '9' };
      |                               ^~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:14: main] Error 1
```

Could someone please tell me what is at issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [braced-init-list and unsigned types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336344/braced-init-list-and-unsigned-types) It's the *exact* same issue and explanation (nothing to do with C++20 specifically).

Comment: Thank you, the link said it all. Somewhat confusing that VS accepts this.